# SaaS tool for *simple* requirements definition?

Tags: language-agnostic

I've seen some complex, enterprise tools for requirements like Rymatech's FeaturePlan -- is there something that enables collaboration and best practices for putting Business-Readable, Domain-Specific (or natural language) requirements and acceptance criteria in place?

Comment: Totally not an answer, but FeaturePlan is trash.  We had to use it a few years ago.  The whole team hated it.

Comment: Can you say what features you're looking for in such a tool? For example, in what ways is a document or spreadsheet inadequate?

Comment: Ahh...good points....I guess I wanted something simpler than breaking down the requirements into tickets used in Unfuddle and when skimming featureplan thought that, somehow, it made life easier (?)  

What I'm doing now is creating individual tickets around (as best as I can) a specific scenario or step in a workflow with the behavior driven tests...it's pretty tedious and wondering if there are good examples out there.

Comment: there had been a tool I saw that stored tests on an ongoing basis so that you could write requirements and then the tests and as you continued to build it out, you could cumultatively test...can't remember the site though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look http://sourceforge.net/projects/rth/. An open source tool for requirements management.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try www.tracecloud.com . Its free (up to 500 requirements) and I have seen some good reviews about it.

Comment: FYI: TraceCloud cost in brief: free for 1 year, $85/mo/user for read+write; $50/mo/user readonly

Answer (score 0):

There's also GatherSpace - http://gatherspace.com/

I tried it a bit about a year ago.  Didn't stick for me, but might work for you.

Comment: GatherSpace looks a little stiff to me for use in a lightweight team - seems more aimed at large organizations that like heavy documentation of requirements, less for agile, which is where my needs are.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at SpiraTest which does [requirements and test management](http://www.inflectra.com/SpiraTest), some people I know have had some success with it.